# Stationarity conditions for IPs

Tags: integer-programming, kkt-conditions

Let's consider the following (MQ)IP:

$\min x^T Q x$

s.t. $g(x) \geqslant 0$

$x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ $i \in I$

By ignoring the integrality constraints we end up with the QP:

$\min x^T Q x$

s.t. $g(x) \geqslant 0$

Whose lagrangian function would be:

$\mathcal{L}(x, \lambda) = x^T Q x - \lambda^T g(x)$

And whose stationarity condition would be:

$\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = 2 Q x - \lambda^T \nabla_x g = 0$

Which allows us to build the following problem:

$\min \frac{1}{2} x^T (\lambda^T \nabla_x g)$

s.t. $2 Q x - \lambda^T \nabla_x g = 0$

$g(x) \geqslant 0$

$0 \leqslant g(x) \perp \lambda \geqslant 0$ (Orthogonality condition)

If, we try to place back the integrality constraint, the stationarity condition not necessarily will be maintained, thence, on this reasoning, I though in adding slacks to the stationarity condition, and penalize them in the objective function.

$\min \frac{1}{2} x^T (\lambda^T \nabla_x g) + \sum_{i = 1}^n \epsilon_i$

s.t. $\epsilon \geqslant 2 Q x - \lambda^T \nabla_x g \geqslant - \epsilon$

$g(x) \geqslant 0$

$x_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ $i \in I$

$0 \leqslant g(x) \perp \lambda \geqslant 0$

I conducted some few experiments over a quadratic problem, and I could manage to make the new objective solution ($\frac{1}{2} x^T (\lambda^T \nabla_x g) + \sum_{i = 1}^n \epsilon_i$) match the original objective function ($f(x)$) for integer assignments.

I would like to know if someone ever tried to adapt stationarity conditions for IPs.
Of course, one may argue about binary transformation + $x_i (1 - x_i) = 0$ $\forall i \in I$, but I am looking for a strategy that does not rely on adding more non linearities.

Comment: Your orthogonality condition is automatically satisfied for any $\lambda$ given the constraint $g(x)\ge 0$ in the preceding line. Was that constraint not meant to be included?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Well, AFAI see, the orthogonality constraint will be satisfied, for a given $(x^{'}, \lambda^{'})$ only if $g(x^{'}) = 0$, or $\lambda^{'} = 0$. Simply stating that $g(x^{'}) \geqslant 0$ isn't enough for ensuring complementarity, since the relation $g(x^{'}) > 0$ if then $\lambda^{'} = 0$ is not covered by $g(x^{'}) \geqslant 0$.

Comment: I may be misreading your notation. What do you meant by $a \perp b$?

Comment: The orthogonality/complementarity constraint, thus $a \perp b$ stands for $a = 0 \vee b = 0$.

Comment: The corner stone of my question concerns the use of the $\epsilon$, I am not sure if it is enough for guaranteeing that at least an integer optimal solution will be retained by the KKT reformulation.